# Creating elements based on values in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSLT.
   I have a source XSLT like the below one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
   <root>
      <child-value>3</child-value>
   </root>
```

My target should have something like the below one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
 <pass_details>
    <pass id ='p1'>1</pass>
    <pass id ='p2'>2</pass>
    <pass id ='p3'>3</pass>
 </pass_details>
```

The number of `<pass>`  tag should be based on the value of `child-value` tag?
Can any one help with the xslt?

Comment: Where is this related to [tag:xquery] after all? Please restrict to _relevant_  tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're limited to XSLT 1.0, you will have to call a recursive template to generate the `pass` elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <pass_details>
        <xsl:call-template name="gen">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="child-value"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </pass_details>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="gen">
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:if test="$n > 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="gen">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <pass id="p{$n}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
        </pass>
    </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k. this wrks.  One more doubt, Is there any way to convert the date which is string into xsd:date sourceXML : <endDate>2016-07-08T02:05:58.058Z</endDate> targetXML must have <endDate>2016-07-08+05:58</endDate> . In source it is string, where the target expect this as xsd:date. any suggestions.

Comment: I am sure there is - but please post this as a new question.

Comment: I have a doubt on the execution of the above xsl.  How does the executon happens for the '<xsl:if test="$n > 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="gen">
            <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <pass id="p{$n}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$n"/>
        </pass>
    </xsl:if>   '  whether template will be called first or the pass tag will be executed then the template is called. suggest any tutorial for xslt. thanks

Comment: The recursive call is executed before outputting the `pass` element. That is because the counter is counting backwards: 3 , 2, 1, and you want the output in reverse order: 1, 2, 3.